# Load mp4 movie located on client PC

Tags: flash, actionscript

Is it possible to load an mp4 movie into a flash swf, with the mp4 been located on the client PC, and the swf loaded from a server in a html page?

Answer (score 0):

In order to play directly from the client machine, you would need the full file path...which you can't get from a FileReference instance for security reasons. Your best solution will be to have the user first upload the .mp4 to your server or FMS. There may be an applet that the user could install and communicate with your flash application, but again, this could present a lot of security issues to work around.